# Passing variable for model issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbonejs app that has a parent view like:

```
var LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(options) {
      if (options) {
        _.extend(this, options);
      }
      this.render();

      alert(this.model); //Alerts Object Object like it's supposed to

      _.each(this.model.get("library").books, function(book){
          var bookView = new BookView({
              el: $('#books'),
              book: book,
              model: this.model
          });
          bookView.render();
      });
   }
});
```

and my bookView looks like:

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
       if (options) {
          _.extend(this, options);
       }
       alert(this.model); // Alerts undefined
    }
});
```

Basically, I'm trying to pass this.model from LibraryView to BookView, but when I do this, BookView's `alert(this.model)` alerts Undefined?

I should mention that when I `alert(this.book)` on my BookView, it's not undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `this` has changed context within the _.each. There are a million of posts about it so i won't explain.
End you each like this (with a this) to keep context:

```
   _.each(this.model.get("library").books, function(book){
          var bookView = new BookView({
              el: $('#books'),
              book: book,
              model: this.model
          }, this);
```

also look into Underscore's _.bindAll
http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll

Comment: If the context of `this` changed, why would I be able to do `alert(this.book)` on my bookView?

Comment: I tried your answer, but passing `this` doesn't seem to fix the issue?

Comment: because you are passing `book` to your `BookView`, but passing the not working `this.model` as the model. In your each; `this.model` is nothing. `this` now refers to your each, there is no `model` object in your each, but there is the `book` object. Please search for this context and read into it, it's kind of complicated, once you get it you know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your question relates to the way that `this` is defined. What `this` means in the body of a function is controlled by how you called the parent function. Luckily, `_.each` allows you to pass in the context (context is what this equates to in the body of the function) as an optional third argument. Docs here: http://underscorejs.org/#each.

The unfortunate part is that this only binds the value of this for the first function, which is the anonymous function you passed into the `_.each` function. This does not bind `this` for when you call the `BookView` constructor since it is a separate function. When you call a function it creates a separate scope, meaning a different value for this(among other things). One solution is to use `bind` for your constructor.

Try this:

```
  _.each(this.model.get("library").books, function(book){
      var bookView = new BookView({
          el: $('#books'),
          book: book,
          model: this.model
      }).bind(this);
      bookView.render();
  }, this);
```

Further reading can be found here on different ways `this` is defined and how to use `_.bind` and `_.bindAll`: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html